# Accepted answer is not the one OP used

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395016/jquery-ui-dialog-outer-window-scrolls-while-scrolling-inside-the-dialog) question.
The accepted answer had two votes, the better answer had 19 votes.
Based on a comment, the OP used an answer that was not the accepted answer (the one with more votes).

> What should I do in this situation?

I thought about leaving a comment for the OP, to accept the answer that he used. However I don't have enough rep to comment.

> If I had enough rep, would commenting to the OP be an acceptable solution?

*Note: I did up-vote the 'better' answer, because that is the one I found helpful..*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Nothing can stop you from commenting.

Chances are it was just a mistake. If the OP decides not to do anything, or just forgets or ignores it, just step back. You can't do anything about it. They're the ones who make the decision, and you won't really change it.

Comment: Not enough rep will stop someone from commenting

Comment: @RyanWeaver Not anymore :)